# Htaccess code to remove id and title from URLs?

Tags: php, database, apache, .htaccess, url

I have used my .htaccess file to add `www.` to index url , remove `.php` and remove `?id=` from URLs.

This is original url:

```
www.site.com/article.php?id=12&title=title-text
```

Url with .htaccess code

```
www.site.com/article/12
```

This code have removed `&title=title-text` from url.

How to remove `&title=` without `title-text`? Like this:

```
www.site.com/article/12/title-text
```

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ifeelvideos.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.ifeelvideos.com/$1 [L,R=301]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

#Alternate default index pages
DirectoryIndex first.html index.htm index.html index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming that article.php doesn't actually need the title to operate, only the id. You can only add the title to the url if the title exists in the url in the first place. You can leave out the second rule if `title` is always in the url.

```
# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123&title=456 to /dir/123/456
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&]+)&title=([^&\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2/%3? [R,L]

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php?id=123 to /dir/123
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\s([^.]+)\.php\?id=([^&\s]+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo/12 to /dir/foo.php?id=12
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/([^/]+)(/[^/]+)?/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Furthermore, article.php should check `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` and perform a redirect if the title is not in it:

```
<?php
  $id = intval( $_GET['id'] );
  $title = titleById( $id );

  $parsedurl = explode( "/", $url );
  if( $parsedurl[3] != $title ) {
    header( "Location: http://www.example.com/article/$id/$title", true, 301 );
    exit();
  }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.Your code working without any issue.I hope this code will help to someone.For css, js, images make sure to use absolute paths.